# Better Way to Use Switch Case?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, label, constant-expression

so my problem is that I'm trying to write a program that uses a switch case to tell a function which case to do. I tried to include an or statement into the switch cases so that I could have a range of values for each case but it seems to be presenting me with an error. Is there a fix to this problem using the switch case or am I simply misusing the switch case and should try a different method? Thanks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int Random(int);
void Movement(void);
int main()
{
int healthratio=5;
switch(healthratio){
case healthratio>0 || healthratio<=10:
printf("%d.\n",healthratio);
break;
case healthratio>10 || healthratio<=20:
printf("%d.\n",healthratio);
break;
case healthratio>20:
printf("%d.\n",healthratio);
break;
}
}
```

When I run this code I get this error "error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant"

Comment: You need to use if-else statements instead of the switch statement.

Comment: `switch/case` is used when you have an expression and want to test it against set of known constants, not conditions.

Comment: You want to use `&&` for comparisons like this: `healthratio>0 || healthratio<=10`. As written it is always true. You still can't use this in a switch/case, but just a general note since it would be a bug in an if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
case healthratio>0 || healthratio<=10
```

This is not valid in standard C, some compilers allows the use of [case ranges](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html), i.e. `gcc` and `clang`:

```
case 0 ... 10:
    printf("%d.\n",healthratio);
    break;
```

But if you can not use them then you are forced to define all cases:

```
case 0:
case 1:
case 2:
...
case 10:
    printf("%d.\n",healthratio);
    break;
```

or use `if` statements: `if (x >= 0 && x <= 10) ...`

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (6.8.4.2 The switch statement)

> 3 **The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant
> expression** and no two of the case constant expressions in the same
> switch statement shall have the same value after conversion. There may
> be at most one default label in a switch statement. (Any enclosed
> switch statement may have a default label or case constant expressions
> with values that duplicate case constant expressions in the enclosing
> switch statement.)

However in labels like this

```
case healthratio>0 || healthratio<=10:
```

the used expression is not a constant expression. Moreover if you used a constant operands of the expression `healthratio>0 || healthratio<=10` then depending on whether the expression is true or false you had a label either

```
case 0:
```

or

```
case 1:
```

That is it is not what you are expecting.

Instead of the switch statement you should use if-else statements like

```
if ( healthratio>0 && healthratio<=10 )
{
    printf("%d.\n",healthratio);
}
else if ( healthratio>10 && healthratio<=20 )
{
    printf("%d.\n",healthratio);
}
else
{
    printf("%d.\n",healthratio);
}
```